# Variable with " " in Python

Tags: python

Trying to make a for loop work in Python I came across a variable declared with "".
i.e: res=""
What is the purpose of the quotes?

Want to know what happens in there.

Comment: it is simply an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res=""` is an empty string. This can be used later to, for example:

- Add another string to it: res += "ABC"
- Check whether there is a result. An empty string returns `False`, while a string with at least 1 character returns `True`.
- Check the length of the string by `len(res)`.

I could go on but you get the point. It's a placeholder.